# commandline output lines that are specified in another file

Tags: unix, command-line, text-processing

iam searching for some command line that takes a text file and a file with line numbers (one on each line) (alternatively from stdin) and outputs only that lines from the first file.

the text file may be several hundreds of MB large and the line list may contains several thousands of entries (but are sorted ascending)

in short:

- one file contains data
- another file contains indexes
- a command should extract only indexed lines

first file:

```
many lines 
of course they are all very different
and contain very important data
...
more lines
...
even more lines
```

second file

```
1
5
7
```

expected output

```
many lines 
more lines
even more lines
```

The second (line number) file does not necessarily have to  exist. Its data also may come from stdin (in deed this would the optimum). Also the format of that data may vary from the shown if this would make the task easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be an approach:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} FNR in a' file_with_line_numbers file_with_data
many lines 
more lines
even more lines
```

It reads the `file_with_line_numbers` and stores the lines in an array `a[]`. Then it reads the other file and keeps checking if the line number is in the array, in which case the line is printed.

The trick used is the following:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {something; next} {other things}' file1 file2
```

that performs actions related to `file1` in the `{something}` block and then actions related to `file2` in the `{other things}` block.

---

### What if the line numbers are given through stdin?

For this you can use `awk '...' - file`, so that stdin is called with `-`. This is called [Naming Standard Input](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Naming-Standard-Input.html). So that you can do:

```
your_commands | awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} FNR in a' - file_with_data
```

#### Test

```
$ echo "1
5
7" | awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} FNR in a' - file_with_data
many lines 
more lines
even more lines
```

Comment: is there a way to avoid the `file_with_line_numbers` and use stdin instead?

Comment: Probably. Give an example of how your stdin would be given (format, etc) by updating your original post.

Comment: since i gather those line numbers from other text manipulating commands via pipes the input format does not really matters since i can adapt it very easily. but at first lets assume that it is the same as in the file - one number per line.

Answer (score 2):

With sed, convert the line numbers to a sed program, and use that generated program to print out the wanted lines;

```
$ sed -n "$( sed 's/$/p/' second_file )" first_file
many lines 
more lines
even more lines
```

Comment: Very clever approach. I didn't know that `sed -n "2p <new line>
> 3p" file` would work.

Comment: i did not get this working on my cmd.exe the awk thingens does work i got `sed: -e expression #2, char 2: Unknown command: "("` - seems that a very old sed is in my path

Comment: even with 4.2 it does not work. seems that this script is incompatible to windows

Comment: @vlad_tepesch, why did you tag your question "unix" if you are working in windows?

Comment: @glennjackman because i wanted some magic with the usual command line text processing tools that ships with unix-style OS because windows largely lacks of theese kind of tools. and usually i have theese tools installed and mostly they work exactly the same like on unix.

Answer (score 0):

This works too.

foreach line ( "`cat file2`" )
foreach? sed -n "$line p" file1
foreach? end

many lines
more lines
even more lines